# Which of the following statements are true about finite cyclic groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

$1.$ If $G$ is a finite cyclic group, then for every subgroup $H,K$ of $G,$ we have either $H\subset K$ or $K\subset H.$

$2.$ If for every subgroup $H,K$ of a finite group $G,$ we have either $H\subset K$ or $K\subset H,$ then $G$ is cyclic.

I have figured a counterexample for the first statement:
Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_{6}.$ Then $H=2\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ and $K=3\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ are subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ but neither $H\subset K$ nor $K\subset H.$ So the first statement is wrong.

However, I am not sure about the 2nd statement.

Comment: For the second statement: consider the case when $H,K$ are cyclic.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: For 1), a more general counterexample would be $\Bbb Z_{pq}$ and its subgroups isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p$ and $\Bbb Z_q$, for primes $p\neq q$.

Comment: The second statement is true and an easy way to see this is to observe that such a group must have a unique maximal subgroup. It follows from that the group must be cyclic of prime power order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The statement is true. Suppose $G$ is not cyclic, and take an element $g\in G$ of maximal order. Such an element exists because the group is finite. By assumption $\langle g\rangle\ne G$, and so there is some element $x\in G\setminus\langle g\rangle$. Now let $H=\langle g\rangle$ and $K=\langle x\rangle$. We will show that none of these subgroups is contained in the other, and this will be a contradiction.

Since $x\in G\setminus\langle g\rangle=G\setminus H$ it follows that $x\notin H$, and so $K$ is not contained in $H$. So we just have to show $H$ is not contained in $K$. Let's assume $H$ is contained in $K$. Then there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $g=x^n$. It is well known that if $ord(x)=m$ then $ord(g)=ord(x^n)=\frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)}$. If $\gcd(m,n)>1$ then it would mean that $ord(g)<ord(x)$, contradicting the assumption that $g$ has maximal order. So we must have $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Thus there are some $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that:

$$km+ln=1$$

But then note that $x=x^{km+ln}=(x^m)^k(x^n)^l=g^l$, and so $x\in\langle g\rangle$, a contradiction.